# get the value in element value and use it in ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my 2 dropdown here. My problem is, I just want to get the element value in province dropdown and pass the variable in ng-if at the city dropdown. for example the value of the selected province is 3 then the ng-if is value === province.city.province_id. please help. thanks.

```js
$http.get(API_URL + "/register").then(function(response) {
  $scope.countries = response.data['countries'];
  $scope.provinces = response.data['provinces'];

  //alert(response.data['provinces'].toSource());
  /*$('select[id=selProvince]').change(function() { 
      var tempProv = $(this).val(); 
      
     });*/



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-group-default">
  <label class="">Province</label>
  <select id="selProvince" class="full-width" data-placeholder="Select Province" data-init-plugin="select2" tabindex="-1" title="">

    <option ng-repeat="province in provinces" value="{{province.id}}">{{province.name}}</option>

  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-group-default">
  <label class="">City</label>
  <select id="selCity" class="full-width" data-placeholder="Select City" data-init-plugin="select2" tabindex="-1" title="">

    <option ng-repeat="province in provinces" ng-if="value === province.city.province_id" value="{{province.city.id}}">{{province.city.name}}</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your js code?

Comment: Did you try `$scope.value`?

Comment: I have this function inside my js but I cant get the variable inside the function to my js to call it at my html

Comment: $('select[id=selProvince]').change(function() { 
var tempProv = $(this).val(); 
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ng-model.

```
<select id="selProvince" class="full-width" data-placeholder="Select Province" data-init-plugin="select2" tabindex="-1" title="" ng-model="provinceSelected">

<option ng-repeat="province in provinces" value="{{province.id}}">{{province.name}}</option>
```

Then in second select box

```
<option ng-repeat="province in provinces" ng-if="provinceSelected === province.city.province_id" value="{{province.city.id}}">{{province.city.name}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-model

```
<div class="form-group form-group-default">
     <label class="">Province</label>
     <select id="selProvince" class="full-width" ng-model="selProvince" data-placeholder="Select Province" data-init-plugin="select2" tabindex="-1" title="">
        <option ng-repeat="province in provinces" value="{{province.id}}">{{province.name}}</option>
     </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-group-default">
     <label class="">City</label>
     <select id="selCity" class="full-width" data-placeholder="Select City" data-init-plugin="select2" tabindex="-1" title="">
         <option ng-repeat="province in provinces" ng-if="selProvince === province.city.province_id" value="{{province.city.id}}">{{province.city.name}}</option>

     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: have you updated both the ng-model in first select box and the ng-if in the second select box

Comment: I guess you missed `ng-if="selProvince === province.city.province_id"` in the second select box

Comment: use double equal to instead of trible and just check whether you have some error in the console

Comment: I have this query in my controller

$country = Country::All();
        $province = DB::table('city')
        ->join('province', 'province.id', '=', 'city.province_id')
        ->select('province.*')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
       
        return array('countries'=>$country , 'provinces'=>$province);

Comment: Good to hear that! But wat were you missing initially ?

Answer (score 0):

Its working now thanks to all who answer :) you guys rock! this what I did

```js
 $http.get(API_URL + "/register").then(function(response) {
   $scope.countries = response.data['countries'];
   $scope.provinces = response.data['provinces'];
   $scope.cities = response.data['cities'];
   //alert(response.data['provinces'].toSource());
   /*$('select[id=selProvince]').change(function() { 
      var tempProv = $(this).val(); 
      
     });*/



 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-group-default">
  <label class="">Province</label>


  <select id="selProvince" class="full-width" ng-model="selProvince" data-placeholder="Select Province" data-init-plugin="select2" tabindex="-1" title="">

    <option ng-repeat="province in provinces" value="{{province.id}}">{{province.name}}</option>

  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-group-default">
  <label class="">City</label>
  <select id="selCity" class="full-width" data-placeholder="Select City" data-init-plugin="select2" tabindex="-1" title="">

    <option ng-repeat="city in cities" ng-if="selProvince == city.province_id" value="{{city.id}}">{{city.name}}</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

then my laravel controller is:

```
$country = Country::All();
$province = Province::All();
$city = City::All();
return array('countries'=>$country , 'provinces'=>$province , 'cities'=>$city);
```

thank you again.